# 'Clumping' a list in python

Tags: python

I've been trying to 'clump' a list

> I mean putting items together depending on the item inbetween, so `['d','-','g','p','q','-','a','v','i']` becomes `['d-g','p','q-a','v','i']` when 'clumped' around any `'-'`

Here's my attempt:

```
def clump(List):
    box = []
    for item in List:
        try:
            if List[List.index(item) + 1] == "-":
                box.append("".join(List[List.index(item):List.index(item)+3]))
            else:
                box.append(item)

        except:
            pass

    return box
```

However, it outputs (for the example above)

```
['d-g', '-', 'g', 'p', 'q-a', '-', 'a', 'v']
```

As I have no idea how to skip the next two items

Also, the code is a complete mess, mainly due to the try and except statement (I use it, otherwise I get an `IndexError`, when it reaches the last item)

How can it be fixed (or completely rewritten)?

Thanks

Comment: The answer below is good, but I want to say that in general, if you will be accessing elements in an array that are not the specific index you're currently on, it is not good practice to use that kind of for-loop, and you will probably want to use a ranged for-loop. In general.

Comment: @JohnLexus The way he is currently accessing the list will only access the index of the first occurence of any given element

Comment: @user3483203 Well, I would refer you to the first if statement. In any case, you are technically right, but what I am saying that if you will be needing to access another element to get a correct solution, he should do a range for loop. In general it is best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an O(n) solution that maintains a flag determining whether or not you are currently clumping.  It then manipulates the last item in the list based on this condition:

```
def clump(arr):
     started = False
     out = []
     for item in arr:
         if item == '-':
             started = True
             out[-1] += item
         elif started:
             out[-1] += item
             started = False
         else:
              out.append(item)
     return out
```

In action:

```
In [53]: clump(x)
Out[53]: ['d-g', 'p', 'q-a', 'v', 'i']
```

This solution will fail if the first item in the list is a dash, but that seems like it should be an invalid input.

Comment: You're right - it'll never start in a '-'. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using `re.sub`

```
>>> import re
>>> l = ['d','-','g','p','q','-','a','v','i']
>>> re.sub(':-:', '-', ':'.join(l)).split(':')
['d-g', 'p', 'q-a', 'v', 'i']
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is another solution using `itertools.zip_longest`

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> l = ['d','-','g','p','q','-','a','v','i']
>>> [x+y+z if y=='-' else x for x,y,z in zip_longest(l, l[1:], l[2:], fillvalue='') if '-' not in [x,z]]
['d-g', 'g', 'q-a', 'a', 'v', 'i']
```